# Visual Studio Formatting — color objects from namespaces

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've recently gotten into coding in c# with visual studio but I am getting irritated that the classes, structs etc. from imported namespaces aren't getting colored.

Is there a way to change the coloring so it does color those?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  Can you give an example of code that doesn't have the type names highlighted as you expect?

Comment: I am on version 16.7.0. I had made a struct called Hex and everything was coloring correctly I then moved it to a namespace in another file and added an using for that file it was importing correctly cause the code worked fine but now Hex wasnt being colored anymore along with the other stuff I moved. Mathf is also a standard unity function which also doesnt get colored

Comment: I test on my side but I can’t reproduce your issue. Could you share me a simple sample and some reproduced steps?

Comment: here's an example: https://imgur.com/a/vt4bwjW
the Mathf.Abs should be colored but it isn't

there aren't really steps of reproduction sinse I just made a file and typed that in

Comment: i switched to vs code it's fixed now

Comment: What theme are you using?  Make sure under `Tools` → `Options...` → `Environment` → `Fonts and Colors` that `User Types - Classes` and `User Types - Structures` are set to distinguishing colors.  As a sanity test, hover the mouse over the usage of a type and see if the IntelliSense tooltip at least identifies it as such.